# Specifying the password to connect with gcloud MySQL

Tags: shell, docker, gcloud

I want to pass the password along with the user id in the single statement while connecting to the gcloud SQL instance. How will I do that? I tried a few combinations but couldn’t get any solutions.

Ex:

```
gcloud sql connect scegold2-f44e-mysql --user=username --password=password --quiet
```

It shows error around password.

Any help and guidance can I get. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I would suggest you to use the following command:
`gcloud sql connect scegold2-f44e-mysql --user=username`

Once your IP is whitelisted for incoming connections, it will ask you for the password.
In case this does not work for you, please provide the error message that you are getting.

Comment: This works fine but I want to find if there is any way where we can send in one line the password as well as  --user and it will directly make a connection.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/sql/connect#FLAGS), the flags for the `"gcloud sql connect"`command are:

```
--user=USER, -u USER
```

Based on this, you cannot specify the password in the same command line, and even if you create an instance by specifying "no password", it will ask you for the password (in that case you should only press enter).

Comment: Thanx @eespinola I am catching up to this very very late. Extremely sorry and thank you.

Answer (score 4):

The [`expect`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/expect) program can be used in order to pass every argument at once to `gcloud sql connect`, including the password, for example  using this `autoconnect.exp` script:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect -f
   
# Call command with "expect autoconnect.exp $INSTANCE $USER $PASSWORD",
# or place the arguments literally in the script, where the variables are.
set INSTANCE [lindex $argv 0]
set USER [lindex $argv 1]
set PASSWORD [lindex $argv 2] 

set timeout -1

spawn gcloud sql connect $INSTANCE --user=$USER
expect "*Password*"
send -- "$PASSWORD\r"
expect eof
```

What this does is to wait for the `gcloud` command to prompt for the password (`expect "*Password*"` means *wait for a line containing "Password"*) and then feed it the password, and then the database management system is opened as normal.

A nice guide for `expect` [here](https://likegeeks.com/expect-command/).